# Echo a message after an if statement and display it near the dropdown list

Tags: php, echo, message

I have an if statement to check that the first year from the Start Year drop down list that i have is smaller than the year in the End Year drop down list.

[image]

For this reason I want whenever the Start Year is bigger than the End Year to display an error message right next to them .

[image]

How can I do that ?

My code is the below...

```
    <?php

if(isset($_POST['submit_next']))
{

    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $school = $_POST['school'];
    $degree = $_POST['degree'];
    $website = $_POST['website'];
    $start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
    $end_date = $_POST['end_date'];
    $start_year = $_POST['start_year'];
    $end_year = $_POST['end_year'];
    $degree_description = $_POST['degree_description'];

    if($start_year > $end_year)
            {
                echo '<script>ErrorMessage()</script>';
                $good = false;
            }
            else
            {
                $good = true;
            }
            if($good == true){

    $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO education (username,school,degree,website,start_date,end_date,start_year,end_year,degree_description) VALUES ('$username','$school', '$degree', '$website', '$start_date','$end_date', '$start_year', '$end_year', '$degree_description')";

    if(!mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlinsert))
    {
        die('error inserting new record');
    }
    header('Location: work_history.php');
}
}
    else if(isset($_POST['submit_new']))
{

    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $school = $_POST['school'];
    $degree = $_POST['degree'];
    $website = $_POST['website'];
    $start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
    $end_date = $_POST['end_date'];
    $start_year = $_POST['start_year'];
    $end_year = $_POST['end_year'];
    $degree_description = $_POST['degree_description'];

    if($start_year > $end_year)
            {
                echo 'Error Message';
                $good = false;
            }
            else
            {
                $good = true;
            }
            if($good == true){

    $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO education (username,school,degree,website,start_date,end_date,start_year,end_year,degree_description) VALUES ('$username','$school', '$degree', '$website', '$start_date','$end_date', '$start_year', '$end_year', '$degree_description')";

    if(!mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlinsert))
    {
        die('error inserting new record');
    }
}
}



?>
<title>CV Education Form</title>
<form method="post" action="education.php">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />

    <legend style="color: #F87F25; font: bold 18px Tahoma;">Education</legend>
    <br/>
    <label style="color: #01ACEE; font: bold 14px Tahoma;">School <input placeholder="University of Sheffield, Department Of Computer Science" type="text" name="school" size="40" required/> </label>
    <br /><br />
    <label style="color: #01ACEE; font: bold 14px Tahoma;">Degree <input placeholder="70" type="text" name="degree" size="20" required/> </label>
    <br /><br />
    <label style="color: #01ACEE; font: bold 14px Tahoma;">Website <input placeholder="www.sheffield.ac.uk/" type="text" size="25" name="website"/> </label>
    <br /><br />
    <label style="color: #01ACEE; font: bold 14px Tahoma;">Start Date</label>
        <select name="start_date">
        <option value="January">January</option>
        <option value="February">February</option>
        <option value="March">March</option>
        <option value="April">April</option>
        <option value="May">May</option>
        <option value="June">June</option>
        <option value="July">July</option>
        <option value="August">August</option>
        <option value="September">September</option>
        <option value="October">October</option>
        <option value="November">Noember</option>
        <option value="December">December</option>
        </select>
    <br /><br />
    <label style="color: #01ACEE; font: bold 14px Tahoma;">End Date</label>
        <select name="end_date">
        <option value="January">January</option>
        <option value="February">February</option>
        <option value="March">March</option>
        <option value="April">April</option>
        <option value="May">May</option>
        <option value="June">June</option>
        <option value="July">July</option>
        <option value="August">August</option>
        <option value="September">September</option>
        <option value="October">October</option>
        <option value="November">Noember</option>
        <option value="December">December</option>
        </select>
    <br /><br />
        <label style="color: #01ACEE; font: bold 14px Tahoma;"> Start Year</label>
        <select name="start_year" >
        <option value="1979">1979</option>
        .
        .
        .
        .
        <option value="2021">2021</option>
        <option value="2022">2022</option>

        </select>
        <label style="color: #01ACEE; font: bold 14px Tahoma;">End Year</label>
        <select name="end_year">
        <option value="1979">1979</option>
        .
        .
        .
        .
        <option value="2021">2021</option>
        <option value="2022">2022</option>
        </select>      
    <br /><br />
<label style="color: #01ACEE; font: bold 14px Tahoma;">Degree Description</label>
    <br />
    <textarea rows="4" cols="40" name="degree_description"></textarea> </label>

<br />
<input type="submit" value="Next" name="submit_next" style="border: 1px solid #006; color:#F87F25; font: bold 16px Tahoma; border-radius:7px; padding:4px;"/>

<input type="submit" value="Add New & Save" name="submit_new" style="border: 1px solid #006; color:#F87F25; font: bold 16px Tahoma; border-radius:7px; padding:4px;"/>

<input type=button onClick="location.href='personal_information.php'" value='Previous' style="border: 1px solid #006; color:#F87F25; font: bold 16px Tahoma; border-radius:7px; padding:4px;">

<input type=button onClick="location.href='work_history.php'" value='Skip' style="border: 1px solid #006; color:#F87F25; font: bold 16px Tahoma; border-radius:7px; padding:4px;">

</form>
```

Comment: Remove the whitespaces before `<?php`, otherwise `header('Location: work_history.php');` will not succeed.

Comment: it works as I want, I just want to place the error message next to the drop down lists @n-dru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - it has the following advantages:

- it saves you a lot of code looping instead of hardcoding every year option
- the form keeps whatever value was previously chosen
- it puts in whatever error message you want right after the select

  ```
  <label style="color: #01ACEE; font: bold 14px Tahoma;"> Start Year</label>
  <select name="start_year" >
  <?php 
  for ($i = 1979; $i < 2022; $i++) {
      if ($i == $start_year) 
          $sel = 'selected="selected"';
      else 
          $sel = '';
      echo "<option value=\"$i\" $sel >$i</option>\n";
  }
  ?>
  </select>
  <?php
  if (!$good) echo "<span>yada, yada error message</span>\n";
  ?>
  <label style="color: #01ACEE; font: bold 14px Tahoma;">End Year</label>
  <select name="end_year">
  <?php 
  for ($i = 1979; $i < 2022; $i++) {
      if ($i == $end_year) 
          $sel = 'selected="selected"';
      else 
          $sel = '';
      echo "<option value=\"$i\" $sel >$i</option>\n";
  }
  ?>
  </select>      
  <?php
  if (!$good) echo "<span>yada, yada error message</span>\n";
  ?>
  ```

Comment: Undefined variable: good in C:\xampp\htdocs\CVTool\cv\education.php on line 294
yada, yada error message

Comment: Yep, I had to do a couple modifications up above - you'll need to initialize `$good = true;` before you get into any of your `if ...` sections.

Comment: Ermmm. Line 2. Are you just copy/pasting this code? If so, that is NOT what stackoverflow and stackexchange are for!

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would just use javascript to check the fields and display the error, then use PHP only to double check before processing the data.

Look in to javascript form validation.

Comment: It doesn't have any validation if a number from a dropdown list is bigger than a number of another dropdown list

Comment: Checking a number is higher than a number *is* data validation